# Fancybox 2 Custom Close Button and Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, fancybox, infinite-scroll

I am having an issue closing Fancybox using a custom close button on content that is pulled in via Infinite Scroll.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Everything that is included on the page before Infinite Scroll can open and close just fine. For content that is pulled in via Infinite Scroll, I can launch the Fancybox without issue, but upon clicking close, I simply get thrown backup to the top of the page and the Fancybox never closes.

Here is the code I'm using:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="fncy-custom-close">
    <span>Close</span>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        padding : 0,
        scrolling : 'no',
        arrows : false,
        closeBtn : false,
        helpers : {
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.6
            }
        }
    });
    $('a.fncy-custom-close').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what type of content? html inline content, images, etc? are some anchors with class  `fncy-custom-close` also dynamically loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may have been a bug in the plugin, as it seems to have resolved itself. All is good now!